# Minimal amount of transactions

Tags: algorithm

We are given `n` nodes. Every one of them has got some value. Some are less then `0`, some are greater. What is important, sum of all of that values is equal to `0`.

Now, node number `i` is connected to nodes `i-1 mod n` and `i+1 mod n` (so node `0` is connected to `n` and `1`).
Only connected nodes can do transactions between themselves. A transaction is sending some value from one node to another - it can be any value we wish, of course greater than `0`. We need to calculate the minimum amount of transactions to even values of all nodes - so after the transactions, all nodes would have the value of `0`.

Some ideas how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried something yet, and is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Thats an old task from some programming contest. I've thought of going clockwise and counterclockwise and cummulating the value, but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: So the values are like bank accounts and the transactions are like payments?

Comment: `(so node 0 is connected to n-1 and 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Let **MINCOST(i,r)** be the minimum number of transactions required to zero out the first *i* nodes, sending **r** (maybe negative) total value to the right to node i.  Since the total value in nodes **0** through **i-1** must be zeroed, the total value sent to the right also determines the total value sent to the left.  We will count the cost of sending to the right to node **i**, but not the cost of sending to the left to node **n-1**

The answer we're looking for is the minimum **MINCOST(n,r)** for all **r**.

Let **Z(x) = 0** when **x=0**, and **1** otherwise.

Define **MINCOST(0,r) = 0** for all **r**

And we can calculate how the costs change when we extend the region by one node to the right:

Let **value[i] = x**.  Then:

**MINCOST(i+1,r) = MINCOST(i,r-x) + Z(r-x)**

So, with the above, it would be possible to come up with an **O(N^2)** dynamic programming algorithm pretty easily, but we can actually do **O(N)** if we use the right representation for the values of **MINCOST(i,?)**

Notice that when we transition from **i** to **i+1**, the values associated with costs shift.  We can just accumulate the total shift instead of actually shifting stuff.  Also all the costs are incremented except for the cost at one particular value.  We can just accumulate the amount added to all costs, and then remember the single value at which the cost should be decremented.

So for any **i** the whole function **r -> MINCOST(i,r)** can be represented by the bag (multiset) of cost-decremented values, and the total accumulated value and cost shift, and we can update this in constant time for each increment of **i**.

At the end, just find the value with the most decrements and subtract the number of decrements from to total accumulated cost shift to find the best cost for zeroing out the whole array.

The code is actually much shorter than the explanation.  Here's a python implementation:

```
def minTransactions(nodeValues):
    shift=0
    decrements={0:0}
    for nodeValue in nodeValues:
        shift+=nodeValue
        decrements[-shift] = decrements.get(-shift,0)+1
    mostdecs=-1;
    for k in decrements.keys():
        if decrements[k] > mostdecs:
            mostdecs=decrements[k]

    return len(nodeValues)-mostdecs
```

You can see it run here, extended to actually print out the transactions:

https://ideone.com/gkJadt

Answer (score -1):

If there are 0 nodes with non-zero values, the minimum number of transactions is 0.

It is not possible to have only 1 node with a non-zero value, because then the sum would not be 0.

If there are exactly two nodes with non-zero values, the minimum number of transactions is `d`, the shortest distance between the nodes with non-zero values (might be clockwise, or it might be anticlockwise). This is because one node must have a value of the negation of the other node's value, in order for the sum to be 0, so the transactions simply send the value around the circle to annihilate its negation.

If there are exactly three nodes with non-zero values, then the solutions of sending all the positive value(s) the shortest way(s) around the circle to annihilate the negative value(s), and sending all the negative value(s) the shortest way(s) around the circle to annihilate the positive value(s), will have the same number of transactions, so it doesn't matter which way you choose to do it. And indeed, there will be 2 nodes with one sign (positive or negative) and 1 node with the opposite sign. Here we have to calculate if it will save time for one of the two nodes to send its value to the other, which will then bundle it up with its own value, or whether to send in the other direction to the node with the opposite sign. So for each of those 2 nodes there is a binary choice to be optimised - clockwise or counterclockwise.

Extending this solution to more than 3 nodes with non-zero values is left as an exercise to the reader ;)